# Custom font changes words in Greek Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uibutton

I want to integrate Ubuntu font into my app.

I change the font for one of UI elements with this way. self.mnhmeiaBtn is an UIButton.

```
[self.mnhmeiaBtn setTitle:@"Μνημεία" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.mnhmeiaBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Ubuntu" size:10]];
```

Although when i run my app the title of button(Μνημεία) appears wrong.

I have two screenshots. One with right result but with system font and another wrong result from Ubuntu font.

**It is strange that if i change viewController and go back to this viewController the words appear to right format...**

[image: right result]
[image: wrong result]

Comment: Is that Greek? You need to find a font that is fully compatible with Greek alphabet.

Comment: Yes it is greek. Is this the problem?

Comment: @Desdenova i read that is fully combatible with greek language

Comment: Try to use that font in any other software and see if you can type that letter properly.

Comment: I wrote in TextEdit and it was written properly.

Comment: Do you have a jailbroken device with ubuntu font installed? If so, I guess it is a coding problem. Try to normalize the UTF.

Comment: No i have not a jailbroken device. The same problems appears to simulator too.